# How to show screen of my Android Device on a Wireless projector

Tags: screen-sharing

I want to project my android screen content on a wireless projector.

Can anyone help me in understand **how stuff works** for [EZ Display](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionsmicro.ezdisplay)?

I have a requirement to project docs/images/videos of an android device on to a Projector/TV wireless.

Comment: See my answer to similar question here http://android.stackexchange.com/a/67231/51412.